# java mail api, imap folder UIDNEXT is always -1

Tags: java, email, imap, uid

hi i fetch mails using java api from imap folder, i can get headers etc but the UIDNEXT is always -1, but the next coming mail has a value like 100.

Is UIDNEXT not supported by ail mail servers?

```
UIDFolder ufolder = (UIDFolder) folder;
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
IMAPFolder iFolder = (IMAPFolder) folder;

int totalMessages = iFolder.getMessageCount();
int unreadMessages = iFolder.getUnreadMessageCount();
int newMessages = iFolder.getNewMessageCount();
int deletedMessages = iFolder.getDeletedMessageCount();
boolean bNew = iFolder.hasNewMessages();
long uidnext = iFolder.getUIDNext();
```

I get proper values for other parameters than UIDNEXT, but uidnext is always returning -1?

Comment: UIDNEXT is universally supported. Can't remember the last time I saw anyone not support that.

Comment: Courier IMAP server does not return uidnext on open.

Comment: Not all email servers implement uidnext. (I have [integrated a couple](https://sharedbox.app/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation at https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getUIDNext(), it depends on your server:

> Servers implementing RFC2060 likely won't return this value when a folder is opened. Servers implementing RFC3501 should return this value when a folder is opened.

Try to close the folder before calling getUIDNext().